# Is it possible to update parentID as part of a move operation without using temporary columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem I have is that I have an old database where there typically are a lot of tables with internal parent/child relationship. These tables are getting migrated to a newer data structure, but we want to keep the old relationship. Today I do this as follow:

```
Old table is tbl_contract. PK: contract_pk, FK: contract_parent_id, contract_name
New table is contract. PK: ID, FK contract_parent_id, name

ALTER TABLE contract ADD contract_pk INT NULL
INSERT INTO contract ( [name], contract_pk )
    SELECT contract_name, contract_pk FROM dbo.tbl_contract
UPDATE contract SET contract_parent_id = 
    (SELECT c.id FROM contract as c WHERE c.contract_pk = 
         (SELECT contract_parent FROM tbl_contract 
          WHERE contract_pk = contract.contract_pk)
     )
ALTER TABLE contract DROP COLUMN contract_pk
```

Is there any easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming ID is a identity column and has the same type as contract_pk, you can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` to allow you to override the auto-generated identity column with the old values:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT contract ON

INSERT INTO contract ( ID, contract_parent_id, [name] )
SELECT contract_pk, contract_parent_id, contract_name FROM dbo.tbl_contract

SET IDENTITY_INSERT contract OFF
```

Assuming you have an FK constraint on contract_parent_id, you'll likely need to disable that first as well, then re-enable it after doing the insert.

Comment: That would work, although I'm a bit skeptical to how this would work if say I have pk's 1,2,3,8,9. What ID's would SQL server insert next time then? 4 or 10?

Comment: @devzero - according to the documentation, it looks like it would be 10: "If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for the table, SQL Server automatically uses the new inserted value as the current identity value."